# html and css not linking

Tags: html, css

My html and CSS files are not linking even though they're in the same directory.
here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>temp</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

</head>
```

I also tried using `href="/main.css"` and `href="./main.css"` but to no avail.
would appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: did you try separating it as an individual folder? or href="../main.css"?

Comment: Could it be that you have compile first you code?

Comment: @Crystal yeah that's the first thing I tried, sadly it doesn't work out either

Comment: @MaikLowrey I did compile and rerun my server, didn't do the trick unfortunately

Comment: You are able to call your site on your browser? But the styles not working, right?

Comment: @MaikLowrey yes correct

Comment: You are able to call: `http(s)://localhost/main.css`. Did you see your stylesheet?

Comment: @MaikLowrey would that even work if my CSS file were to be working? regardless I did try it and nope it didn't show, even when I load up my page, go and inspect element and fetch the sources, my CSS file doesn't show up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243945/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-moalzoabi).

Comment: @moalzoabi try like this href="../../main.css" or partials/main.css

Answer (score 2):

Use this app.use(express.static('public')); awesome talking to you guys.

Comment: that is the right solution! +1up from me!

Comment: awesome you guys. glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='./main.css' />
```

i don't know why it is not working for you. but it should work!!!
have you tried restarting your app??

try it.
close and then restart.

Comment: managed to get it fixed, I had to put ```app.use(express.static("public"));``` in my server.js, ty tho!

Comment: I did ofc as well end up creating a folder for my css file rather than having it in the same folder as my html.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding this snippet after title block

```css
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: ty for your answer what does bootstrap have to do with it? regardless, I did try it and nothing happened, some tiny changes to some elements happened but I'm not looking to use bootstrap

Comment: I assume, you must've worked with bootstrap. I encountered a similar situation and ended up clearing by adding bootstrap. Glad the issue is resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).